# Database output makes php commented

Tags: php, database, comments

thanks allready for helping me out with this.
The following problem occurs:

I have a function named "news()". This function correctly works. However when I try to call this function form a database, the problem occurs.

I have the following data stored in my database:

```
Table MENU
menu_id (int) -> 1, menu_name(varchar(255)) -> Home, menu_content (longtext) -> <?php news() ?>, menu_status (varchar(255)) -> visible, menu_rank (varchar(255)) -> active.
```

As you can see, i stored the follwing PHP statement in my database "`<?php news() ?>`".

When I collect the data from my database with the following query's:

```
$content_query = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM MENU WHERE menu_id = '".$var."') or die (mysql_error()); 
$content = mysql_fetch_assoc($content_query);
$menu_content = $content['menu_content'];
$menu_title = ['menu_title'];
```

When I echo my $menu_title is shows the data correctly. If I echo my $menu_content, it shows nothing. When I try to debug, it seems that there has been made an HTML comment for that data. Like this:

```
<!--?php news();?-->
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?
Thanks allready for helping me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to do what you're trying to do, You'll have to eval() the returned data. You must be VERY careful when you decide to use the eval function. Be ABSOLUTELY SURE that no user data makes it's way to your eval statement!  Not sure about the "<!--" though. Give it a try.

Comment: Thank! This made it work for me.
For people who want to see the actual code:

    echo '<div class="menu_title"><h1>'.$menu_title.'</h1></div><div class="menu_content"><h2>';eval(' ?> '.$menu_content.' <?php '); echo '</h2></div>';

Comment: If this is the answer that helped you, could you please click the checkmark to accept my answer? Also, PLEASE, PLEASE, PLEASE be careful using eval. Rasmus Lerdorf, the author of the first version of PHP, has been quoated as saying "If eval() is the answer, you're almost certainly asking the wrong question."

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a closing quote `"` at the end of the SQL statement:

```
"SELECT * FROM MENU WHERE menu_id = '".$var."'
```

Should be:

```
"SELECT * FROM MENU WHERE menu_id = '".$var."'"
```

(note the ending quote character)

More concise:

```
"SELECT * FROM MENU WHERE menu_id = '$var'"
```

Comment: Thanks but i still have this problem. When i put other content in my database, the output is correct. When i have an PhP statement in it, it doesn't show.

Answer (score 0):

Your first line is missing a closing '"'. To fix this simply replace this:

```
$content_query = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM MENU WHERE menu_id = '".$var."') or die (mysql_error());
```

with this:

```
$content_query = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM MENU WHERE menu_id = '".$var."') or die (mysql_error());
```

I would also recommend adding intval() around the $var variable if this is a user input. Otherwise a malicious user could inject the SQL to edit your database. This will just convert any text value into an integer.

Also, just to confirm, are you using a PHP server as I have seen this error when somebody tries to output a PHP function while in a .html file or in a .php file without PHP installed.